# Survey Permissions to hide Action Bar in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, survey

I made a survey and gave to certain user Contribute permission to answer the survey.
Appears that even if you give to user "Read" permissions Action bar is still available.
Is there any chance to hide "Action bar" for limited permission users?

Answer (score 0):

I recently made an intranet survey for the business team. I only gave the link gave by "Respond to this survey". The EditForm.aspx and NewForm.aspx had a custom master page with low level display.

For the action menu, you can personnalize button by setting permission level (for example : you deselect on **Site permissions** the permissions *Use remote interface* and *Use Client Integration Features* in order to hide the extract to excel datasheet action button.

Comment: I Deselected both permissions and it didn't worked. I deselected them exactly on Site permissions: Site Axtions -> Site Settings -> Advanced Permissions (User and permissions group) and then made my own permission by copying Limited Access Permission and then deselected those two permissions. I'm still able to export to excel and see results.

Answer (score 0):

You may use some temporary solution like using JQuery to hide it. Use as follows:

```
$(".ms-menutoolbar td:eq(2)").hide();
```